# Proving why $\Bbb Z_{4} \rightarrow \Bbb Z_{6} \text{ given by } f(\overline x) = [2x+1] $ is not a function.

Tags: functions, relations, equivalence-relations

**Question presented:** Is following a function from the indicated domain to the indicated
co domain?

> $f:\Bbb Z_{4} \rightarrow \Bbb Z_{6} \text{ given by }$
>   $ \bbox[white,1px,border:1px solid red]{f(\overline x) = {\left [ 2x+1\right]}
> }
> $

Q.S: So my main question for this problem is how does the co domain $f(\overline x) = [2x+1] $ affect the equivlanece class $\Bbb Z_{4}$?

QS: So according to my work here would it be correct to assume that $\Bbb Z_{4}$ would change because of the codomain.

Q.S: Lastly how does $x =y(mod)m$ affect the final result of the problem?

In this case we represent an element of the domain as an $\bar x$ and use the notation $[x]$ for equivalence classes in the co-domain.

The set of equivalence classes for the relation $\cong_{m}$ is denoted $\Bbb Z_{m}.$

$f(\overline0) = [1],f(\overline1) = [3],f(\overline2) = [5],f(\overline3) = [7],f(\overline4) = [9],f(\overline5) = [11],f(\overline6) = [13] $

$(4x+0)*2+1 \;\text{ This is what I am doing to get the result for the work bellow for  } \Bbb Z_{4} $ $x$ is an integer that is being multiplied to get the result it 
is a visual representation for the function.

$\Bbb Z_{4},\; \overline 0 = \{ ...,-15,-7,1,9,17,... \} \; \Leftarrow \Rightarrow(4x+0)*2+1 $

$\overline 1 = \{ ...,-13,-5,3,11,19.., \} \Leftarrow \Rightarrow \; (4x+1)*2+1$

$\overline 2 = \{ ...,-11,-3,5,13,21,... \}$

$\overline 3 = \{ ...,-9,-1,7,15,23..., \}$

$\Bbb Z_{6}, \; \overline 0 = \{ ...,-12,-6,0,6,12,... \} \Leftarrow \Rightarrow \qquad (6x+0) $

$\overline 1 = \{ ...,-11,-5,1,7,13,... \} \Leftarrow \Rightarrow \qquad (6x+1)$

$ \overline 2 = \{ ...,-10,-4,2,8,14,... \} \Leftarrow \Rightarrow \qquad (6x+2)$

$ \overline 3 = \{ ...,-9,-3,3,9,15,... \} $

$ \overline 4 = \{ ...,-8,-2,4,10,16,... \}$

$ \overline 5 = \{ ...,-7,-1,5,11,17,... \}$

The reason for this not being a function is because $\Bbb Z_{6} \;  \overline 0 \neq \overline4 \; $ or $[1] \neq [9] $

Comment: Your notation is so confusing. What's $(4x+0)*2+1$? What do you mean by $\Bbb Z_4\ \bar 0 = \{ \dots, -7,1,9,\dots\}$? Didn't you just say that $\bar 0$ is an equivalent class in $\Bbb Z_4$?

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "the codomain affect the equivalent class $\Bbb Z_4$"? How can the codomain possibly affect the domain?

Comment: $1\equiv5\pmod4$, yet $f(1)=3\not\equiv f(5)=11\pmod6$

Comment: @BigbearZzz I believe the OP is  writing  $\Bbb Z_{4}$ in front of $\bar 0$ and $\bar 0$ refers to the equivalence class to the right of the equals sign. I think co-domain is just an error on his part, he just means domain.Also,his general formula for modular arithmetic-(4x+ n)*2 +1 where $n\in \Bbb Z_{4}$-is correct.

Comment: I cannot comprehend your claim like $\overline 2 = \{ ...,-13,-5,3,11,19,... \}$, how did you manage to conclude that?

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 That still doesn't make sense to me since $\overline 1 \ne \{ ...,-14,-6,2,10,18.., \},\ \overline 2 \ne \{ ...,-13,-5,3,11,19,... \}$ and such.

Comment: @BigbearZzz Yes,the formula is right,but he/she clearly made serious errors in his/her computations!

Comment: @BigbearZzz Basically,the reason this isn't a function is that it's not well defined i.e. 2 different ordered pairs in f can have the same first member.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Yep, that's quite obvious. The reason I was asking is because the OP had just recently made a similar question (almost identical) with notations as confusing as in this one. I was trying to help him/her clarifying them so more people can understand him in the future.

Comment: I have made grievous mistake. Allow me to correct these indiscretions. For $\Bbb Z_{4}, \overline1 \rightarrow \overline3 $ is not correct.

Comment: Waiting for the third installment of THE SAME question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer the question in the title:

The function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/6$, $x \mapsto [2x+1]$ does not descend to a function on $\mathbb{Z}/4$ because $x_1 \cong  x_2 (mod \,\, 4) \nRightarrow f(x_1) \cong f(x_2) (mod \,\, 6)$.  You can check this explicitly for the choices $x_1=0$, $x_2=4$.

Answer (score 0):

It is an onto relation from a set of lesser to a set of greater cardinality. Thus it is not a function by definition of cardinality.

Comment: Why is it onto? You should give an exmaple in order to improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$1\equiv5\pmod4$, yet $f(1)=3\not\equiv f(5)=11\pmod6$

That is, $f(x)=2x+1$ is not well defined as a function from $\mathbb{Z}_4$ to $\mathbb{Z}_6$; choosing a different representative for $x\bmod4$ gives a different residue class for $f(x)\bmod6$.